terraform tags for list variable not working
trying to create aws resources , i get problems in tags , can some one please help
but i want to merge tags with local.tags and with the addition tags for the resource creation , i think something to do with list and object ,
provider "aws" {
  region = var.aws_region
  default_tags {
    tags = local.tags
  }
}

locals {

   tags = {
    Application     = var.stack
    Owner           = var.owner
    CostCenter      = var.cost_center
    Project         = var.stack
    environmentCode = var.environment_code
    Environment     = var.environment
    Cmdb            = var.cmdb
  }
}

data "aws_ssm_parameter" "environment" {
  name = "/ss/environment"
}

resource "awscc_elasticache_serverless_cache" "elasticache" {
  serverless_cache_name = "${data.aws_ssm_parameter.environment.value}-serverless-elasticache"
  description           = "Generic ElastiCache Redis Serverless"
  engine                = "redis"
  major_engine_version  = 7
  daily_snapshot_time   = "03:00"
  snapshot_retention_limit = 7
  security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.elasticache_access.id}"]
  subnet_ids          = module.vpc_data.subnet_ids
  depends_on = [aws_security_group.elasticache_access]
  kms_key_id            =  data.aws_kms_key.ucm.id
  tags = merge(
    local.tags,
    {
      Name   = "${data.aws_ssm_parameter.environment.value}-ucm-elasticache-serverless"
      "Description" = "ECS security group for ${var.stack} running on ${local.environment}"
    },
  )
}

Error:

│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on main.tf line 68, in resource "awscc_elasticache_serverless_cache" "elasticache":
│   68:   tags = merge(
│   69:      local.tags,
│   70:      {
│   71:        "Name"        = "${data.aws_ssm_parameter.environment.value}-ucm-elasticache-serverless",
│   72:        "Description" = "Elasticache serverless for ucm"
│   73:      }
│   74:     )
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.tags is object with 7 attributes
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "tags": set of object required.

Even as per https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/awscc/latest/docs/resources/elasticache_serverless_cache
 tags = [{
    Name   = "${data.aws_ssm_parameter.environment.value}-ucm-elasticache-serverless"
    Description = "Elasticache serverless for ucm"
  }]


Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on main.tf line 68, in resource "awscc_elasticache_serverless_cache" "elasticache":
│   68:   tags = [{
│   69:     Name   = "${data.aws_ssm_parameter.environment.value}-ucm-elasticache-serverless"
│   70:     Description = "Elasticache serverless for ucm"
│   71:   }]
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "tags": element 0: attribute "key" is
│ required.


Are you sure this is the code you are using? Because, e.g, the Name tag references the local variable called environment.

yes marko , i also have a datasource for environment , data "aws_ssm_parameter" "environment" {
name = "/ss/environment"
}

But the first code block shows this: "Name" = "${local.environment}-${var.stack}-service-container-sg-${count.index}". There is no count meta-argument in that block as well. Are the local variables correct?

thanks Marko , i edited the question but the error is same

Based on the documentation you linked, the tags seem to need to be provided with:
  tags = [
    {
      key   = "Name"
      value = "${data.aws_ssm_parameter.environment.value}-ucm-elasticache-serverless"
    },
    {
      key   = "Description"
      value = "ECS security group for ${var.stack} running on ${local.environment}"
    }
  ]

In other words, it seems you would need to explicitly define the keyword key for the tag key and value for the tag value. You would have to repeat something similar for the rest of tags you want, but it might work with default_tags as well. Make sure to check that when running terraform plan.
EDIT: Since all the tags require having the key and value keys, a new local variable elasticache_serverless_tags can be defined like the following:
locals {
   tags = {
    Application     = var.stack
    Owner           = var.owner
    CostCenter      = var.cost_center
    Project         = var.stack
    environmentCode = var.environment_code
    Environment     = var.environment
    Cmdb            = var.cmdb
  }

   elasticache_serverless_tags = [
     {
       key   = "Application"
       value = var.stack
     },
     {
       key   = "Owner"
       value = var.owner
     },
     {
       key   = "CostCenter"
       value = var.cost_center
     },
     {
       key   = "Project"
       value = var.stack
     },
     {
       key   = "environmentCode"
       value = var.environment_code
     },
     {
       key   = "Environment"
       value = var.environment
     },
     {
       key   = "Cmdb"
       value = var.cmdb
     },
  ]
}

Then, in the resource block:
  tags = toset(concat(local.elasticache_serverless_tags,
  [
    {
      key   = "Name"
      value = "${data.aws_ssm_parameter.environment.value}-ucm-elasticache-serverless"
    },
    {
      key   = "Description"
      value = "ECS security group for ${var.stack} running on ${local.environment}"
    }
  ]))

The old local variable tags has to stay the same since it is referenced in the default_tags which requires having a map.
EDIT 2: An even easier way, with less code repetition, would be the following:
locals {
   tags = {
    Application     = var.stack
    Owner           = var.owner
    CostCenter      = var.cost_center
    Project         = var.stack
    environmentCode = var.environment_code
    Environment     = var.environment
    Cmdb            = var.cmdb
  }

  elasticsearch_serverless_tags = [for k, v in local.tags : {
    key   = k
    value = v
  }]
}

The concat and toset would be used the same as in the previous example in the tags argument of the resource.

tags = merge([
local.tags,
{
key   = "Name"
value = "${data.aws_ssm_parameter.environment.value}-ucm-elasticache-serverless"
},
{
key   = "Description"
value = "ECS security group for ${var.stack} running on ${var.environment}"
}
])

thanks Marko , the first one worked it seems Key id expected by default but cant do the merge with default tags  i get

│     │ while calling merge(maps...)
│     │ local.tags is object with 7 attributes
│     │ var.stack is a string
│
│ Call to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects, got
│ "tuple".

getting tuple error

I have edited the answer, not sure if it will work though.

thanks Marko , unfortunately did not work  Error: Incorrect attribute value type
Error: Incorrect attribute value type
on main.tf line 4, in provider "aws":
4:     tags = local.tags
├────────────────
│ local.tags is tuple with 7 elements
Inappropriate value for attribute "tags": map of string required.
make: *** [/Makefile:96: terraform_validate] Error 1

@Dilu sorry, I wanted to use concat instead of merge, fixed it.

i know it is bit annoying and frustrating but the result is same

Ah, ok, I think I know where the error is coming from. I just fixed it. The old local variable tags has to stay as is, and you just need to add a new one which will be used in the resource.

that was magical , great support much much appreciated but curious why it is so complex this time ??

for all other resources ,  the below simply worked only for serverless resource i have this issue tags = merge(
local.common_tags,
{
"Name"        = "${local.environment}-${var.stack}-service-container-sg-${count.index}"
"Description" = "ECS security group for ${var.stack} running on ${local.environment}"
},
)

Well, it's just a guess: the AWS CC provider might be doing something different with tags then when using the regular provider.

great guess much appreciated , i have one more question , not sure if i ask here or another question , incase here then a question , i have simple redis resource creation using terraform , this is not multi az enabled , is there any simple way to just changed it to multi az using same terraform state file ?? redis version 7 , thanks

That should be a separate question.

thank u so much @Marko

The hashicorp/awscc provider is generated from the CloudFormation schemas provided by AWS, and so this different shape of tags is based on the CloudFormation schema for tags, which uses a set of objects with Key/Value attributes instead of a map from strings to strings as is conventional in the hashicorp/aws provider.
